# Game with AngularJS/Phaser.io and destroy method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phaser-framework

I am making a game with a friend and we have some problems with AngularJS and Phaser.

So, we have a page named game, it has a template, a controller and a factory.
There is a page who "redirect" us to the game page (just with a link).

In the template :

```
<div id="game"></div>
<a href="#/page">Back</a>
```

In the factory :

```
// function prealod and create ....
init: function(data) {
     game = new Phaser.Game(width, height, Phaser.AUTO, 'game', { preload: preload, create: create });
},
destroy: function() {
     game.destroy();
}
```

In the controller :

```
gameFact.init();
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
     gameFact.destroy();
});
```

Of course, there are more code.

**The problem is simple :**

If i come to the game page, Phaser load very well the game (we just display a map with sprites).
After that, i click on the back button and reclick on the link to return to the game page.
If i do that 7 times, there is an error in the console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'AudioContext': number of hardware contexts reached maximum (6).
```

And after few seconds, i have this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gain' of undefined
```

I already search on the web, and the solution are :

1. Use an iFrame (I really don't think that iFrame is a good solution)
2. Use the destory method (it doesn't work)

**Do you know how to solve this problem ?**

If you have any ideas, don't hesitate. Even if you use another game framework (maybe it works the same way).

Comment: Not sure if you want to keep state when switching routes, but a simple `target="_self"` on the anchor will force angular to re-load everything.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser but it doesn't work. I still have this error in the console : 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'AudioContext': number of hardware contexts reached maximum (6).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, it seems that `destroy()` doesn't work correctly [(issue discussed here)](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/1092) with the current version:

```
Could you please test out the dev branch, which has lots of fixes for this in.
```

I resolved the issue by using the dev branch [(available here)](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/tree/dev)

Comment: Which version of dev branch are you using?

Comment: @jjwallace this was a while ago, I think the main branch should be working fine now. But I think it was the 2.1.0-dev branch

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an Angular directive and using the navigation event to do that, check my example: http://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionphaser

Regards, Nicholls

Answer (score 0):

There's a new WebComponent to integrate Phaser with any other Framework https://github.com/proyecto26/ion-phaser